# unit tests option in Resharper is missing

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual studio 2017 and Resharper 17.1.3. My colleagues are using the same version. For some reason I had to re-install the resharper and noticed that Unit Test option is missing. I uninstalled and installed again but still it's missing. When I use the shortcut(ctr+U, ctr+I), I get a notification that Resharper_UnitTestRunSolution is not currently available.

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that "Unit Testing" feature is enabled here:

1. ReSharper | Options | Environment | Products & Features | Features | Unit Testing
2. ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | MSTest/NUnit/xUnit.net | Enable "..." support.